# Xtrabackup 8.0 Error

Tags: mysql, backup, ubuntu, percona

I'm using Percona MySQL 8.0.20 running on Ubuntu 18.04 on an AWS ec2 m5.2xlarge instance. The Xtrabackup version being used is 8.0.14.

While testing the restore process, I'm getting the error as listed in this pastebin link: https://pastebin.pl/view/74b1832d

I'm also listing a snippet of the entire error listing -

```
...
Open file list len in shard 31 is 0
Open file list len in shard 32 is 9
InnoDB: Assertion failure: dict0dict.cc:1216:table2 == nullptr
InnoDB: thread 140008395342336InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.percona.com/projects/PXB.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
15:30:33 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x55bc783d1800
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 7ffe5f6a38b0 thread_stack 0x46000
xtrabackup(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x55bc736ec8dd]
xtrabackup(handle_fatal_signal+0x2fb) [0x55bc7255c32b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x128a0) [0x7f563e6918a0]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0xc7) [0x7f563c6eef47]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x141) [0x7f563c6f08b1]
xtrabackup(ut_dbg_assertion_failed(char const*, char const*, unsigned long)+0xb2) [0x55bc729ddca2]
xtrabackup(dict_table_add_to_cache(dict_table_t*, unsigned long, mem_block_info_t*)+0x11c) [0x55bc726f28ac]
xtrabackup(dd_table_create_on_dd_obj(dd::Table const*, dd::Partition const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Stateless_allocator<char, dd::String_type_alloc, My_free_functor> > const*, bool, unsigned int)+0x1938) [0x55bc72717238]
xtrabackup(+0x144cc65) [0x55bc72718c65]
xtrabackup(dd_table_load_on_dd_obj(dd::cache::Dictionary_client*, unsigned int, dd::Table const&, dict_table_t*&, THD*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, Stateless_allocator<char, dd::String_type_alloc, My_free_functor> > const*, bool)+0x53) [0x55bc72718cd3]
xtrabackup(dict_load_tables_from_space_id(unsigned int, THD*, trx_t*)+0x665) [0x55bc72042155]
xtrabackup(+0xd766c3) [0x55bc720426c3]
xtrabackup(+0xd7bfe0) [0x55bc72047fe0]
xtrabackup(main+0xd37) [0x55bc72006787]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7) [0x7f563c6d1b97]
xtrabackup(_start+0x2a) [0x55bc720344ca]

Trying to get some variables.
Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
Query (0): Connection ID (thread ID): 0
Status: NOT_KILLED


Please report a bug at https://jira.percona.com/projects/PXB
```

Any pointers to this would be of great help.

Comment: Your pastebin link just goes busy and never returns to the browser.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME (if possible) 
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
F) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
G) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.